# javaScript for Sidebar Button To Show and Hide Aside in Small Devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries, show-hide

just like my title states, i am trying to show and hide Aside in small screens. bellow is the code but it's not working

I want to belive that what I am trying to achieve here is not that complex. i just need help  achieving it and learning more

```js
const sidebar = document.querySelector('aside');
const showSidebarBtn = document.querySelector('#show__sidebar-btn');
const hideSidebarBtn = document.querySelector('#hide__sidebar-btn');


const showSidebar = () => {
    sidebar.style.right = '0';
    showSidebarBtn.style.display = 'none';
    hideSidebarBtn.style.display = 'inline-block';   
}


const hideSidebar = () => {
    sidebar.style.right = '100%';
    showSidebarBtn.style.display = 'inline-block';
    hideSidebarBtn.style.display = 'none';   
}


showSidebarBtn.addEventListener('click', showSidebar)
hideSidebarBtn.addEventListener('click', hideSidebar)
```

```css
   .dashboard aside {
        position: fixed;
        box-shadow: 2rem 0 4rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        left: -100%;
        height: 100vh;
        transition: var(--transition);
        background: var(--color-bg);
    }
    
    ----------------------------------------
    #hide__sidebar-btn {
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container dashboard__container">
        <button id="show__sidebar-btn" class="sidebar__toggle"><i class="uil uil-angle-right"></i>
        </button>
        <button id="hide__sidebar-btn" class="sidebar__toggle"><i class="uil uil-angle-left"></i>
        </button>
        <aside>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="add-post.html"><i class="uil uil-edit-alt"></i>
                    <h5>Add Post</h5>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="manage-posts.html"><i class="uil uil-edit"></i>
                    <h5>Manage Posts</h5>
                    </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
        </aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te class `.dashboard` in the style is not in your html code.

For running the code below I changed background: var(--color-bg) in yellow.

The second part in the css is optional if you want `<aside>` always shown on larger browser views.

I did use (in JS and CSS) the left:0% and left:-100% , not the right propery.

```js
const sidebar = document.querySelector('aside');
const showSidebarBtn = document.querySelector('#show__sidebar-btn');
const hideSidebarBtn = document.querySelector('#hide__sidebar-btn');

const showSidebar = () => {
    sidebar.style.left = '0';
    showSidebarBtn.style.display = 'none';
    hideSidebarBtn.style.display = 'inline-block';   
}

const hideSidebar = () => {
    sidebar.style.left = '-100%';
    showSidebarBtn.style.display = 'inline-block';
    hideSidebarBtn.style.display = 'none';   
}

showSidebarBtn.addEventListener('click', showSidebar)
hideSidebarBtn.addEventListener('click', hideSidebar)
```

```css
.dashboard__container aside {
  position: fixed;
  box-shadow: 2rem 0 4rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  transition: var(--transition);
  background: yellow;
}
#hide__sidebar-btn {
  display: none;
}

/* if you want to show always on larger browser view */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .dashboard__container button {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .dashboard__container aside {
    left: 0% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container dashboard__container">

  <button id="show__sidebar-btn" class="sidebar__toggle"><i class="uil uil-angle-right"></i>Show</button>
  <button id="hide__sidebar-btn" class="sidebar__toggle"><i class="uil uil-angle-left"></i>Hide</button>

  <aside>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="add-post.html"><i class="uil uil-edit-alt"></i>
        <h5>Add Post</h5>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="manage-posts.html"><i class="uil uil-edit"></i>
        <h5>Manage Posts</h5>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </aside>

</div>
```